How to make Nginx not respond to unwanted requests?
I have a few proxy servers in front of the servers that host my website. I've set up Nginx on the website server so that requests to my website servers not coming from the IP addresses of one of my proxy servers will get rejected, since I want all traffic to go via those.
Is it possible to set it up so that my server doesn't respond at all to unwanted requests?
I would like to make it seem like the IP address doesn't have any server listening behind it.


I would like to make it seem like the IP address doesn't have any server listening behind it.

That's something that needs to happen before it gets to Nginx. The server isn't listening for individual requests as such – it is listening for TCP connections through which the HTTP requests might arrive; and no matter how you configure request handling in Nginx, your OS has already accepted the TCP connection to port 80 and revealed the HTTP service's existence before any requests even get sent.
Use your server's firewall configuration (iptables, pf, ufw...) to prevent unwanted addresses from making the TCP connection to port 80 or 443.

Ah okay, thank you!
